# Interpreting questions on EI report when doing temporary work

Tags: canada, insurance, unemployment

There are several questions on the [bi-weekly employment insurance report](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/ei/employment-insurance-reporting.html) that are difficult to know how to answer. I often work temporary jobs, a few weeks or months at a time.

> Did you start a full time job during the period of this report?

If I started temporary work where I worked 30+ hours in a week, but just for the one week, should the answer be yes or no?

> Provide the total amount of earnings (including tips or commissions)
> before deductions from all employers as well as any self-employment
> earnings after deducting operating expenses for the first week of this
> report.

What counts as "deductions"? Does this mean before tax is taken off? I have had some jobs were the agency takes a percent off, is this considered a deduction?

> The following question will give you the opportunity to inform us of
> any loss of employment that you have not already reported to us. Have
> you stopped working for any employer during the period of this report?

First, does it make a difference if I was considered a contractor because that would mean they are not technically an "employer"?

Second, I was told that if I am working a temporary job with a fixed end date, that on the next report I would answer yes to this question. But doing so temporarily ends my EI claim and I have to call in to answer questions. This seems very backwards to me and they were not able to explain it.

It is not unusual to spend hours on hold to talk to someone from the EI department. Even then they are not always able to explain things (or transfer me to a department that is closed). Of course I want to provide true and correct information but is there some sort of expectation that if I'm unsure just guess? For example if I get a weeks worth of work, choose "yes I stopped working for an employer" then I have to spend hours on hold.